# how to get a human readable time to javascript time

Tags: javascript, php, timestamp

Ok, so I have tried all sorts of thing without getting the result I wanted

I have a sql database filled with timestamps (and data) that needs to get plotted in a highchart

Seems I need to convert it to a javascript timestandard, in milliseconds sinds 1 jan 1970

My database timestamp format looks like this  " 2014-07-14 03:37:28 " 
and needs to get to the javascript format

I'm using a piece of php code to extract the data from the database and trow out a json format of the data, but would love some help on how to convert the string into the timestamp i need for the graph, preferably in php.

Hope someone can help me out here

this is the php code used

> 

Comment: Put it into _ISO 8601_ (simple transformation from what you've shown us) and _Date_ should understand it

Comment: simple way, [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime) should work fine. proper way, use the [date time class](http://www.php.net/datetime). Both ways you can get a unix timestamp and just multiply that by 1000 to get milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The propiest that comes to my mind is to create a Date objet with something like:

```
var str_date =  "2014-07-14 03:37:28";
var year = str_date.substring(0,4);
var month = ...;
var day = ...;
var hours = ...;
var minutes = ...;
var seconds = ...;
var your_date = new Date(year, month-1, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

I let you fill the "..." I think you get the idea. Be careful with the months, they start from 0.

Hoped it helped!

Answer (score 0):

1st you want to change date and time to timestamp by this

```
$utime  = strtotime(date($db_date));
```

2nd take the date value and inserted as a js var

```
var jsdate = '<?php echo $utime?>';
```

Comment: i tried the $series4['data'][] = strtotime( $r['time']);
but for 2014-07-10 19:26:52 i get 1405013212 . is this correct ? 
shouldednt it have more digits , im not seeing the logich here ,thanks for your help

Comment: ok , i found out that the response is now a unix time , but ill need a javascript timestamp for the highchart to work (if im right that is :p)

Comment: or is that just as simple as multiply by 100.0  ?

Comment: you need to multiplu by 1000, to achieve JS timestamps.

Comment: OK , ive did that , but didnt get the expected result , anyone care to look at my graph and tell me why i cant get the time/date on the xasis  ?? . my grap can be found at www.ice-control/stock/index.html
thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry this link is broken www.ice-control/stock/index.html